# VDSL2 profile 17a maximum upload speed?

Tags: vdsl

I live in a semi-rural location and have a VDSL2 connection on a 17a profile.   My download speeds are about 48 megabit, and **upload speed about 10 megabit**.    Depending on how I measure it, I believe the cable takes an approximately 1km route to my house (between 950 and 1100 meters).

I am contemplating getting a second VDSL connection (as I can't get fibre) to the edge of my property and then back hauling it over wifi/ethernet/fibre to try and eek out a little more upload speed.   I am hopeful I will be able to save about 100 meters of cable to the termination point of the VDSL device.    I am not expecting miracles as from memory a VDSL connection about 500 meters from the same cabinet is getting about 80 down/20 up but I am unsure what profile the connection is on.

(I have investigated getting fibre, and the cost is prohibitive.  As am almost unimportant aside, adding about 12 meters to the distance to the vdsl modem in my house did not make a discernible difference - the last 12 meters being made over cat 5e cable or better - the VDSL connection is the only thing on the line - no filters or other devices)

The question I have is this -

**Will decreasing the copper run from about 1km to about 900m make a noticeable difference to my *upload* speed?**  Bonus if anyone can make an educated estimate how much my upload speed will increase by.

Comment: Isn't bonded VDSL2 a thing? That might be a better solution than what you're proposing.

Comment: @spiff2 - thank you for the thought. I doubt that bonded VDSL2 [at the telco level] is an option for my use case.  I don't know what the telco support for it is like (what I found online says our providers don't do it, but that info is over 10 years old), but I do know that when I was more involved in these things the controlling telco charged 2 arms and 2 legs for dsl using multiple pairs.   (I'm after a regular residential install).   I may very well do some pseudo bonding at the router level, as this will be a second connection.

Comment: Probably an unnoticeable difference by removing 100m of good copper cable. What you really want to clean up are splices, bridge taps, coils, etc. IOW perform a TDR scan. See http://www.ttswebsite.com/manuals/mtt_tdr.pdf

Comment: @Sawdust - revisiting this +and your link) I dont think that my line has an issue - im fairly sure its a distance-from-the-exchange issue. (Also, performing this kind  of work is beyond mt reach as its not my copper)